# Calculate Standard Deviation Given Mean and Probability Only (Normal Distribution)

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

Let's say we have a central range $(24.5, 27.2)$ and there is a 90% probability value x is within this range, as in $P(24.5 < x < 27.2 = 0.9.$ The range is normally distributed.

The mean value is = $$\frac{(24.5 + 27.2)}{2} = 25.85$$

How do I calculate the standard deviation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.  Then we know that the part of the distribution we are integrating to get 90%${}=0.90$ is from the $Z$-score $\frac{24.5 - 25.85}{\sigma} = \frac{-1.35}{\sigma}$ to $Z$-score $\frac{27.2 - 25.85}{\sigma} = \frac{1.35}{\sigma}$.  A way to proceed is from a table of cumulative standardized normal values -- find the pair of symmetric $Z$-scores for 5% and 95%, between which we find 90% of the probability mass.  Call these $Z_{0.05}$ and $Z_{0.95}$.  Then either solve $\frac{-1.35}{\sigma} = Z_{0.05}$ or solve $\frac{1.35}{\sigma} = Z_{0.95}$ for $\sigma$ (since both will yield the same $\sigma$).